# Django: Cron job is not executing python script

Tags: python, django, cron

I am using csvimporter to import some a csv file into a Django model. I have 2 scripts - one python script to take the file:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("python manage.py csvimport --model='csv_reader.csv' /Users/path_to_csv", shell = True)
```

And a django script to delete objects from the model:

```
from csv_reader.models import *

csv.objects.all().delete()
```

Both of the scripts work fine when ran manually from the shell. But when I add a cron job to perform the execution of the scripts, it's not working, although it logs them in cron log:

```
Feb 25 10:21:00 Liubous-MacBook-Pro.local /usr/sbin/cron[43055]: (yudasinal1) CMD (/Users/path_to_script)
```

I tried adding a cronjob like this:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings
* * * * * /Users/path_to_csv/test_subprocess.py
```

Where in the actual script I added `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of the file.

As well as I tried adding this cronjob:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings
    * * * * * python /Users/path_to_csv/test_subprocess.py
```

All of them are logged into cron log, but unfortunately, the actual functions are not being executed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use celery instead :)

Comment: I was thinking of using celery at first, but then I thought that maybe for these 2 simple operations celery might be too much, as it offers way more than just scheduling tasks

Comment: (9h later) if you still have this problem, do consider using celery :)   lol

Comment: @pleasedontbelong I think you might be right :P Gonna try celery now haha

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1: Add Shebang to script

Unix scripts use a line called "[Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)"

So your first line should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

## Stept 2: Make script executable

1. Go to the folder with your script `mysript.py`
2. Execute `chmod +x myscript.py` in console.
3. Verify that it is executable by executing it with `./myscript.py`.

## Step 3: Add it to CRON

1. Type `crontab -e` in terminal.
2. Add a line like this:

   30 13 * * * /home/yourusername/myscript.py
3. Verify with `crontab -l` that everything worked.

(see [cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) for more information)

## Debugging python scripts

```
import datetime
import getpass

now = datetime.datetime.now()

# Open file to append
with open("/home/user/myscript.log", "a") as f:
    f.write("Script started at %i.%i.%i (%i:%i:%i) by %s" % (now.day, now.month, now.year, now.hour, now.minute, now.second, getpass.getuser()))

[...]
with open("/home/user/myscript.log", "a") as f:
    f.write("File 'xy' was opened.")
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion step by step (the script did what it's intended to do when I ran ./myscript.py), and it's also logged in cron log /var/log/cron.log. My cronjob looks like this now: * * * * * /Users/path_to_script/test_subprocess.py   But, unfortunately, when I check if the csv file was imported (that's what the script does), it's not. Do you have any other suggestions of what might be wrong? thanks!

Comment: Hmm. I recently had a strange problem where a TCL script used environment variables. In that case, I could execute the script via tclsh or janus (another shell-like environment) and got different results. Do you use environemnt variables in your script? I'd suggest adding some lines to `test_subprocess.py` that write something into a logfile. Write something at the start (e.g. "execution started at 12:31"), and more logs at "critical" parts (e.g. "opened file xy", "start importing", "end importing", ...)

Comment: @yudasinal: I have never seen stars only in crontab. Rather something like `*/1 * * * * /Users/path_to_script/test_subprocess.py`. But I don't know whats exactly the difference. I think both should be executed every minute.

Comment: yeah, it's quite odd. My script looks exactly like the first code snippet that is in the original question. I am not quite sure, how do I write comments in a file that are going to be put in a log file?

Comment: @yudasinal I've added a little example how you could debug

Comment: and yes, all stars means "execute every minute"

Comment: @yudasinal: Ok, `*` means the same as `*/1`, see [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22012561/562769)

Comment: thanks for your example with debugging. When I run the script manually, it logs it into the log file. With cron, nothing is written in the file. That means that it doesn't even open the file :/

Answer (score 0):

check first your crontab is running. add a job to create a file in tmp folder. IF it is running. try to give full path for python like

***** /usr/bin/python /home/path of your django project/manage.py ...

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal write crotab -e . There put your

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /Users/path_to_csv/test_subprocess.py
```

And in the test_subprocess.py add

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings
```

and also note that DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings will only work if you run this cron job in project folder. So it would be better to use it as DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=/pathToProject/project.settings

Answer (score 0):

## !/usr/bin/env python is fine

just set project setting full path to DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=/Users/path_to_project/project.settings

- - - - - python /Users/path_to_csv/test_subprocess.py

Comment: @Özgür_Eroğlu so I left #!/usr/bin/env python in the file, and changed my cronjob to this: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=/Users/path_to_settings/settings.py * * * * * /Users/path_to_script/test_subprocess.py Nothing works still, unfortunately :(