# Is `*/1 * * * *` and `* * * * *` equivalent in CRON?

Tags: cron

As I have recently seen something like

```
*/1 * * * * ./script.py
```

I would like to know if it means the same as

```
* * * * * ./script.py
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it does.

`*/X` means: every X minutes
`*` means: every minute

So all together `*/1` means exactly the same as `*`.

---

From [`man cron`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html):

> Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  **Following a
> range with /number specifies skips of the number's value through
> the range**.   For  example, `0-23/2'' can be used in the hours field to specify command execution every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard is` 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22'').
>
> Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want to say
> `every  two hours'', just use` */2''.